# Thousand Separator in DBGrid

Tags: mysql, delphi, sum, separator, fastreport

I'm using MySQL and Delphi XE4 to build an application.
There are big numbers in Database and I used FORMAT function in my queries to apply Thousand Separator!

```
SELECT Field1,FORMAT((Field2 * Coef), 0) AS blabla FROM MyTable WHERE .....
```

Everything was fine but When I tried to add SUM function in FastReprot an logical error happend!

FORMAT function returns the result as a string and SUM function concatenates strings!!!

```
SUM(frxDBDataset1."blabla",MasterData1)

Product1| 123,500,000
Product2| 1,455,999,100
________________________________
SUM = 123,500,000-1,455,999,100
```

What is best way for showing thousand separator in DBGrid!
I'm thinking about applying thousand separator in "OnGetText" Event. Does this method cause delay in showing data in DBGrid when recordcount>5000 ?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Use the [DisplayFormat](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DB.TNumericField.DisplayFormat) property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really a bad idea to format your results inside the query. The query should be used to retrieve information... presentation should be handled elsewhere. In this case, I would use (I do use, in fact) the DisplayFormat, as suggested in comments.

You can also write some code to format automatically, if you don't always want to add the fields to the TDataSet on design-time:

```
DataSet.Open;
For I := 0 To DataSet.Fields.Count - 1 Do Begin
    If DataSet.Fields[I] Is TFloatField Then
        (DataSet.Fields[I] As TNumericField).DisplayFormat := '###,###,##0.00'
    Else If DataSet.Fields[I] Is TIntegerField Then
        (DataSet.Fields[I] As TNumericField).DisplayFormat := '###,###,##0';
End;
```

This should be adapted to your actual needs... you could read metadata from BD (this is BD-dependent) to decide on precision, for example.

Inside FastReport, you could also use DisplayFormat, or you can also use the format function inside your memo: `[Format('%.2n', [<DataSet."Field">])]`, where the `.2` indicates the precision to be used.

EDIT: To address the problem of the minus sign appearing on the right with `BiDiMode = bdRightToLeft` (See [this](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.internationalization.win32/200608/060809178.html)), I believe you'll really need to use `OnGetText` event. I think you already found this workaround yourself, but I'm including it nevertheless for completeness:

```
procedure TForm1.FieldGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: String; DisplayText: Boolean);
var
  FmtStr: string;
  F: Double;
begin
  F := Sender.AsFloat;
  FmtStr := TNumericField(Sender).DisplayFormat;
  if Sign(F) = -1 then
    Text := '-' + FormatFloat(FmtStr, Abs(F))
  else
    Text := FormatFloat(FmtStr, F)
end;
```

Comment: Thank you @GabrielF. How can I use DisplayFormat inside FastReport?

Comment: @Jessica Just set your `Memo.DisplayFormat.FormatStr` property to some format string, [the same way you do with Format function](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.Format#Format_Strings) (e.g., `%.2n` to include thousand separators and 2 decimals), and set `Memo.DisplayFormat.Kind` to `fkNumeric`. You should also set the DecimalSeparator to your local one. Alternatively, you can click on the `...` button on the `DisplayFormat` to visually build the property.

Comment: @GabrielF- New Problem: I used OnGetText for some fields and When I use DisplayFormat for them, it does not work !

Comment: @Jessica If you're using OnGetText, DisplayFormat will be ignored, really. You can see this on `TField.GetDisplayText` function. So, if you really need to use OnGetText, you should format the value yourself. You can do this using: `Text := FormatFloat((Sender As TNumericField).DisplayFormat, Sender.AsFloat);`. This will use your DisplayFormat property. But you should probably check if you really need to use OnGetText.

Comment: I have to use RightToLeft DBGrid and minus sign appears in right side of negative numbers (Like 100-), so I have to use OnGetText to handle it! Do you have better idea?! @GabrielF

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. I've never used RightToLeft and was unable to reproduce your problem here (maybe it's locale dependent?)... however, according to the help, this shouldn't affect numeric fields: `For example, with data aware controls, the alignment does not change for the following field types: ftSmallint, ftInteger, ftWord, ftFloat, ftCurrency, ftBCD, ftDate, ftTime, ftDateTime, ftAutoInc`. Maybe it's a bug? Did the workaround with OnGetText work?

Comment: oh GOD ! Look at this :http://s22.postimg.org/f7kwuzxw1/minus.png BidiMode cause this problem and alignment don't changes anything. in OnGetText I simply move minus sign to begin of string!

Comment: You mean everything is ok (with negative numbers) in your DBGrid When BiDiMode is RightToLeft? Is DBGrid.ParentBidiMode=False?! O_o

Comment: ParentBidiMode wasn't set to false... but it is now and nothing changed again. In fact, nothing changes at all... I tried TEdit, TMemo... I believe this is locale related. But there seems to be no solution to your problem: http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.internationalization.win32/200608/060809178.html. So, you'll really need a workaround. I'll edit my answer with a suggested workaround.

Answer (score 1):

With a little change it worked very well. [**Text := FormatFloat(FmtStr, -F) + '-';**]

Special thanks to GabrielF.

```
procedure TForm1.FieldGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: String; DisplayText: Boolean);
var
  FmtStr: string;
  F: Double;
begin
  F := Sender.AsFloat;
  FmtStr := TNumericField(Sender).DisplayFormat;
  if F < 0 then
    Text := FormatFloat(FmtStr, -F) + '-';
  else
    Text := FormatFloat(FmtStr, F)
end;
```